# Javascript: variable = variable.conat(anothervariable);

Tags: javascript

Why doesn't this work:

```
var variable; 
variable = variable.concat(variable2);

$('#lunk').append(variable)
```

I cannot figure this out. Any ideas?

Comment: because variable is `undefined`

Comment: What is your input, what is your expected output?

Comment: @Rajesh undefined will also yield results. Like `NaN` or `undefinedSomething`

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy `+=` will yield output but `.concat` will throw error `concan of undefined is not a function`. Also `Nan` will happen if you add number. Using `+=` on string will return `undefinedStringValue`

Comment: @Rajesh I am not aware of `.concat`. I heard that it is there in array's prototype. Can you share a relevant link for the concat that you guys are talking about.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy there is a concat function in string as well. You can refer [MDN - String.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat)

Answer (score 2):

You declare the variable but if you do not assign a value to it, it stays `undefined`. So what you are effectively doing is:

```
undefined.concat(variable2);
```

This cannot be done. If you assign an empty string (`""`) to the `variable`, it will work:

```js
var variable = "";
var variable2 = "Hello Foo!";
variable = variable.concat(variable2);
document.write(variable);
```

**Note:** *`.concat` is available in `string` and if your value is `numeric`, it will throw error.*

```js
try {
  var variable = 0;
  var variable2 = "Hello Foo!";
  variable = variable.concat(variable2);
  document.write(variable);
} catch (ex) {
  document.write(ex.message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The concat() method combines the text of two or more strings and returns a new string.

Because `variable` is not initialized yet `concat` will not work because it expect to be called on string, so you should initialize by string your `variable` before using the **[concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat)** function, e.g :

```js
var variable="init1",variable2="init2";

variable = variable.concat(variable2);

alert(variable);
```

Comment: Do not use ``alert()`` for debugging purposes.

Comment: Thankd @ssc-hrep3 for your intervention but I'm not debugging here, just showing result...